# View thums images with GridView, scrolling is very slow

Tags: java, android, gridview, scroll

Currently I am in training, I am working on a file management application online.
I have a problem with the scrolling when I try to display many images (100 images or 200) with a thumbs GridView scrolling is very very long.

I download the images from the server I set drawable and layout parameter I set for the small image here is my code:

```
public void openImageWithCache(boolean loopTry, final ImageView iconView,
        final LayoutParams layoutParams, final View v, final Node o) {
    //if (v.getTag() == previewT){
    try {
        String prefix = (true ? "thumb_mini" : "");


        File cacheFile = new File(AjaXplorerApplication.getCacheFolder(),
                (prefix) + previewT.getUuidPath());
        if (cacheFile.exists()) {



            iconView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(cacheFile
                .getPath()));
            iconView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            //iconView.invalidate();
            //loopTry = true;
            return;
            }
```

Comment: `String prefix = (true ? "thumb_mini" : "");` is useless `prefix` will always be equals to `"thumb_mini"` -> `String prefix = "thumb_mini";`.

Comment: _italic_ **bold**  `Thank's i corrected that but i have the same problem with scrolling it still very very slow.`

Answer (score 0):

1. Are the thumb images large? If so minimize them to the smallest size you can.
2. In the getView method in the adapter, if the view is not null do not call "new" , just change the image, according to the position.